# Error in Iphone development - greeting undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0

I Am new Iphone development. And i got his error "greeting undeclared (first use in this function)".I have attached the screen shot file here.

code is below:

```
greetings = [[greeting alloc] initWithName:@"Missing You"
```

andURL1:@"http://dimitko.com/banners/icards/missing/missing1.png"
                                  [image] andURL2:@"http://dimitko.com/banners/icards/missing/missing2.png"
                                   andURL3:@"http://dimitko.com/banners/icards/missing/missing3.png"
                                   andURL4:@"http://dimitko.com/banners/icards/missing/missing4.png"
         andHeader:@"Miss you..."
        andSubject:@"Missing You a Whole Bunch!!!"
          andColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:_RGB2COCOA(236) green:_RGB2COCOA(57) blue:_RGB2COCOA(46) alpha:1]

```
   andColorWeb:@"#ec392e"
  andGreetingFont:@"SnellRoundhand"
   andFontSize:12
    andWebFont:@"5"
```

Answer (score 2):

Import the header that defines your greeting class.

Also, that's quite a wordy initialiser, you should consider just using properties instead.

Comment: Hi,I already tried that one.i cant do.Please find this URL for ur references.  https://picasaweb.google.com/110769400378257789313/September132011?authuser=0&feat=directlink